# Accessing Django's template folder via /static/js/

Tags: python, django, django-static

In a Djano project of mine, I have a JS file inside `/project/static/js/`. It needs access to a files stored at `/project/templates/`. I'm unable to access this location from the js file.

Can someone suggest a work around (short of keeping duplicates of the said files in the JS folder). I'd like to avoid duplication (since it doubles my maintenance down the road)

**Task specifics:** I have some HTML templates that display instructions. The JS I've written simply takes the same instruction text and displays it as text on a dynamic popup.

**Note:** The main wrinkle is that a non-JS fallback must exist for any JS solution. Some of the users of this project emanate from a forward proxy that strips all `<script>` tags. Think [Unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: what about simlinking it?!: `ln -s /project/templates/my_file /project/static/js/my_file`

Comment: @jojo, that wouldn't be the number 1 way I'd do it. Yes it'd work but I don't want to do something on the OS level to solve an issue with the application.

Comment: Sure. I wouldn't do it this way either. But I guess this is more of a design problem. The best solution is one where there is no need to access the template folder from within you static directory, I guess.

Comment: @jojo, precisely, that is the kind of solution I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Any luck? Maybe, if you are more specific on what exactly the JS does you'll have more luck in getting an answer.

Comment: @jojo: I have some HTML templates that display instructions. The JS I've written simply takes the same instruction text and displays it as text on a dynamic popup.

Comment: Can you add views that serve up the templates and then have your js call the urls for those views?

Comment: @jcfollower: : I don't follow. Could you illustrate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to access `projects/templates` from the `static` folder.

You have several options how to display HTML content, like instructions, in a popup.

Here's an outline of 2 ways to do so:

#### *1st Option*: Load all content at once

This approach loads everything in one go and the js only changes the visibility of the instruction pop-up. If you are using Bootstrap then [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) is what will make your life easier. You do not even need to write any js altogether. With Bootstrap this would look something like:

```
<!-- main_template.html -->
<!-- Don't forget to load the bootstrap library here -->
....
<!-- icon to trigger the popup -->
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InstructionModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Show Instructions
</a>
....

<!-- the bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="InstructionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Instructions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {% include 'instruction.html' %}
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the instructions:

```
<!-- instruction.html -->
<p>
  This is an instruction - You must follow it!
</p>
```

#### *2nd Option*: Load additional content on request using [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

In this case you would not load the additional HTML content in the beginning, but serve it only upon request, i.e. if someone clicks on the *Show Instructions* icon. Note that you'll need jQuery for this to work.

Here your instructions get a view (don't forget to update your `urls.py` as well):

```
# view.py
def get_instructions(request):
    return render(request, 'instruction.html')
```

The instructions template is still the same:

```
<!-- instruction.html -->
<p>
  This is an instruction - You must follow it!
</p>
```

The js:

```
<!-- get_instructions.js -->
....
<script>
$("#InstroductionModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
</script>
```

The the main template:

```
<!-- main_template.html -->
<!-- Don't forget to load get_instructions.js -->
....
<!-- icon to trigger the popup -->
<a href="{% url 'get_instructions' %}" data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InstructionModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Show Instructions
</a>

<!-- the bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="InstructionModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Instructions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> Instructions will follow </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Hopefully one of those ways work for you. Unfortunately, I don't have a django project setup, so this code is untested.*

Comment: I'd certainly prefer to use jQuery (method 2) but my issue is I need to support non-JS clients as well. Some of my users emanate from a forward-proxy that strips all `<script>` tags. That's what's been causing the initial wrinkle in my plan. Think Unobtrusive JS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: @HassanBaig but so you cannot use the `<script>` tag our/and you want a non-js fallback solution that also works?! If you cannot use `script` bootstrap is not an option, I guess, or then something like https://github.com/intesso/rework-bootstrap . Maybe you could just add a `target` to the trigger icon popup.

`<a href="{% url 'get_instructions' %}" target="_blank">`